# SharePoint 2007: Showing recently added people in the SharePoint Group

Tags: 2007

We have developed a job that syncs information from Active Directory group onto SharePoint groups.
The job runs everyday and pulls new users added onto Active directory group,

I wanted to know if there is way I can show recently added people from SharePoint Group.  Sharepoint group does not allows to create views.

Any thoughts/ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"developed a job that syncs information from Active Directory group onto SharePoint groups"* - so you developer the User Profile Synchronization Service. Hat tip to you :-)

Comment: Moontear,  thanks for your compliments :) we had a specific business requirement.... :)

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not automatically record the time and date a user was added to a SharePoint group. As you can see the [`SPGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup_members.aspx) does not have a "LastModified" date or something like that - the [`SPUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser_methods.aspx)
 does neither for that matter.

You have two options to get the recently added users to a SharePoint group:

1. You can use [`SPAudit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spaudit.aspx) to generate an event when a user is added to a group, like so (as [explained here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/7aa4292f-86cc-41ed-85b1-b026e81d318a)):

   ```
   using (SPSite site = new SPSite("url"){

           SPAuditQuery auditQuery;
           SPAuditEntryCollection auditCol;

           auditQuery = new SPAuditQuery(site);
           auditQuery.AddEventRestriction(SPAuditEventType.SecGroupMemberAdd);

            // SecGroupMemberAdd: Addition of a new member to a group that is associated with a SharePoint site collection
           //Also some Enum type for group:
           //SecGroupCreate/SecGroupDelete/SecGroupMemberAdd/SecGroupMemberDel

           auditCol = site.Audit.GetEntries(auditQuery);

           foreach (SPAuditEntry entry in auditCol)
           {
                //Execute send mail action here
           }
       }
   ```
2. Check the SharePoint database. This is **not recommended** by Microsoft, but it certainly doesn't hurt to take a peek. The database contains the usual columns like LastModified and CreatedOn so you check which users where added when.

Comment: How do I specify if I need to audit only a specific group and not all the security group

Comment: Not possible. If you look at the SPAuditQuery class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms435524.aspx) you have these methods: `AddEventRestriction`, `RestrictToList`, `RestrictToUser`, `RestrictToListItem` if it helps restricting the query to a list I would do it, but you can't restrict it to only audit one `SPGroup` - you will have to do an `if` in your code.